# $(#form).submit() is not working in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have inserted one hidden form in the page using jquery and i am submitting the form using jquery on button click event.The hidden form is getting submitted in firefox but it does not get submitted in chrome.

Following is the form i have inserted using jquery on document.ready function.

```
$('#leftnav').after(
       "<tr><td><form name='login1'" +        
                "action='https://abc.com/FormPost/Submit' method='post'" + 
                "id='login' >" + 
                "<input type='hidden' name='MerchantIdentifier' value='abc' />" + 
                "<input type='hidden' name='Url'" + 
                  "value='http://chcnq.chxcg.servertrust.com/one-page-checkout.asp'/>"+
                "<input type='hidden' name='Description'" +
                  "value='Volusion Order' />"+
                "<input type='hidden' name='Data' value='' />"+
                "<input type='hidden' name='TransactionIdentifier'"+ 
                  "value='12' />" + 
                "<input type='hidden' name='Amount' value='' />"+
                "<input name='Token' type='hidden' value='" + token + "' />"+
                "<input type='hidden' name='ErrorUrl' />" +
        "</form></td></tr>");
```

and on button click i have written following code:

```
$("#btnSubmitOrder").click(function() {
$("#login").submit();
});
```

Please can you advise why it is not working in chrome browser.

Comment: it's working for me in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/tvsfa/ Just make sure that `token` is set

Comment: is #btnSubmitOrder within another form? does it get submitted?
What I've found earlier:
hitting enter key in form calls first submitButton onclick in firefox, but not in chrome

Comment: yes #btnSubmitOrder is in another form yes that form also gets submitted. Can you please tell me then what i can use so it works in chrome.

Comment: Well, browser then usually redirects to "action" url in that submitted form... It's luck it works in firefox, I think.

Comment: so i cannot do anything to make the hidden form submit in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#btnSubmitOrder").click(function() {
  $("form[name=login1]").submit();
});
```

Comment: yeah I just didn't see the id attribute. It was in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments:

It is generally a bad practice to submit two forms on one action, but:

1) You can add target iframe to your both forms. That way Browser does not get redirected by submittin either of them.

or

2) you can prevent default behavior and send data to #login form url by using $.ajax and then (on callback) call submit on the first form.

Comment: can i take an input type image in the hidden form and trigger its click event on #btnSubmitOrder click function. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript code.

```
$("#btnSubmitOrder").click(function() {

 document.forms['login1'].submit();

});
```